# Attributes Causing Crashing

Tags: swift, xcode, attributes

I recently wrote this bit of code in swift, but for some reason it crashes the app.

```
class ShapeColour : NSObject {
        var colour = ""
        var shape = ""
        var images = UIImage(named: "")
    }

    //Blue Square

    let BlueSquareObject =  ShapeColour()
    BlueSquareObject.setValue("Blue", forKey: "colour")
    BlueSquareObject.setValue("square", forKey: "shape")
    BlueSquareObject.setValue("BlueSquare.jpg", forKey: "images")

    //Red Square

    let RedSquareObject =  ShapeColour()
    RedSquareObject.setValue("Red", forKey: "colour")
    RedSquareObject.setValue("square", forKey: "shape")
    RedSquareObject.setValue("RedSquare.jpg", forKey: "images")

    //Yellow Square

    let YellowSquareObject =  ShapeColour()
    YellowSquareObject.setValue("Yellow", forKey: "colour")
    YellowSquareObject.setValue("square", forKey: "shape")
    YellowSquareObject.setValue("YellowSquare.jpg", forKey: "images")
```

Am I doing something wrong creating the attributes? Any help would be appreciated ;)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to update your question with the errors you are getting. But why are you attempting to set the `UIImage` property named `images` with `String` values?

Comment: Sorry,  I am new to swift. Could you please explain how I am supposed to use the UIimage? @rmaddy

Comment: First, update your question with the errors and point out the lines causing the errors.

Comment: I am not getting errors, the only line in the debugger is "error: attach by process ID '4585' failed
unable to attach"  @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images` property of class `ShapeColour` is type of `UIImage` and you are setting `String` with it.

```
BlueSquareObject.setValue(UIImage(named: "BlueSquare.jpg"), forKey: "images")
```

You need to follow some coding guidelines like object name start with lowercase. Also the simplest way to create object is using `init` that will reduce your code too, So i'm suggesting you to add one `init` method in your `ShapeColour` class like this way.

```
class ShapeColour : NSObject {
    var colour:String
    var shape:String
    var images: UIImage

    init(color: String, shape: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.colour = color
        self.shape = shape
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Now simply call `init` to create instance of `ShapeColour`.

```
let blueSquareObject =  ShapeColour(color: "Blue", shape: "square", image: UIImage(named: "BlueSquare.jpg"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much! has fixed my issue and shortened my code dramatically! (the full list of attributes was 4 times longer ;)

Comment: @Nosh Welcome mate :)